# Division in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

How do I accomplish the following:

I have a cell `C5` with various numerical values.
If `C5` is less than `30` return `0` in `C6`
If `C5` is greater than `30` return `1hr` in `C6`
if `C5` is greater than `60` return `2hr` in `C6`
if `C5` is greater than `90` return `3hr` in `C6` etc..

Comment: What if  `C5 = 30`?

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, you should upvote and/or mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

**If we assume that a value of `30` should return `0`**, then the following formula could be entered into cell `C6`:

```
=CEILING(C5/30) - 1
```

It divides the value found in `C5` by `30`, rounds it up to the nearest integer (the [`CEILING` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093471?vid=1-635753644851552044-1548233328630055970)), and subtracts `1`. This table shows the result of a few selected input values:

```
        Column C
Row 5 => | 29 | 30 | 31 | ... | 59 | 60 | 61 | ... | 89 | 90 | 91 |    
Row 6 => |  0 |  0 |  1 | ... |  1 |  1 |  2 | ... |  2 |  2 |  3 |
```

---

**If instead a value of `30` should return `1`**, use

```
=FLOOR(C5/30)
```

which divides the input value by `30`, and rounds it *down* to the nearest integer (the [`FLOOR` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093487?hl=en&vid=1-635753644851552044-1548233328630055970)).

It will result in the following values:

```
        Column C
Row 5 => | 29 | 30 | 31 | ... | 59 | 60 | 61 | ... | 89 | 90 | 91 |    
Row 6 => |  0 |  1 |  1 | ... |  1 |  2 |  2 | ... |  2 |  3 |  3 |
```